# C# WPF - Create object that loads JSON file upon startup

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I'm making a C# WPF program that creates an object, this objects will read a stored JSON file when it's instantiated. Something like this:

```
namespace CodeTester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            data_init data = new data_init("C:\test.json")
        }
    }
}
```

Where data_init is the object that reads the json file and parses it, and the only parameter that the constructor needs is the filepath. As seen, I put this in the MainWindow constructor, and my program will not load up for some reason, I get an error within the MainWindow constructor, so I know that's where the issue is.

Where can I instantiate this object without it causing errors?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: This is the error that I get:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I tried implementing the following to catch the error, as suggested by Stefan:

```
try
{
    data_init data = new data_init("C:\test.json")
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error:");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

But it seems that the code fails at `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: The issue is most likely in your XAML. Can you post it?

Comment: if it fails at `InitializeComponent();` then it is an error in the xaml/ui

Comment: @John: can you show us the xaml?

Comment: Stackoverflow is often due to an infinite recursion where you have some object in your xaml or ctor is creating something that results in creating that object again. I wonder what the ctor of data-init is doing.

Comment: @John: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work with commenting the following line?

```
// data_init data = new data_init("C:\test.json")
```

If it works maybe you have a big JSON file. Is it the case?